# TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, daterangepicker, ngx-bootstrap

When trying to build an angular project I get the error below. 
I declared my variables, alongside a method to get the different dates.

```
export class AuditComponent implements OnInit {

                minDate: string;
                maxDate: string;
                bsRangeValue: Date[] = [];

                constructor(){}

                ngOnInit() {}

                 getDateRange(evt: any) {
                        this.minDate = moment(this.bsRangeValue[0]).toISOString();
                        this.maxDate = moment(this.bsRangeValue[1]).toISOString();

                        this.auditPage = this.auditService
                            .getAuditEventEntries(0,
                                100,
                                this.userId,
                                this.auditQueryStr,
                                this.minDate,
                                this.maxDate);
                    }

 }
```

How I call date Range

```
<li class="custom" (click)="drp.toggle()">
      div>Custom Range <span class="caret icon"></span></div> </li>
```

template code

```
<input
 bsDaterangepicker
 #drp="bsDaterangepicker"
[(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue"
(ngModelChange)="getDateRange($event)">
```

AOT ERROR

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at createClass (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at createDirectiveInstance (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at createViewNodes (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at Object.createEmbeddedView (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at NgIf._updateView (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at NgIf.set [as ngIf] (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at updateProp (app.js?1516703022201:1)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (app.js?1516703022201:1)
```

Comment: please add your Component code, or at least the part related to the template you posted (`bsRangeValue` attribute, `getDateRange` method)

Comment: Could you provide a reproduction of it via plunkr? here's the template https://plnkr.co/edit/0NipkZrnckZZROAcnjzB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `bsRangeValue` is an empty array, but it should instead contain two `Date` values:

For example: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#examples

component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-date-picker-popup',
  templateUrl: './date-picker-popup.html'
})
export class DemoDatePickerPopupComponent {
  minDate = new Date(2017, 5, 10);
  maxDate = new Date(2018, 9, 15);

  bsValue: Date = new Date();
  bsRangeValue: any = [new Date(2017, 7, 4), new Date(2017, 7, 20)];
}
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" #drp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker [(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-3 form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="drp.toggle()">Date Range Picker</button>
  </div>
</div>
```